# Error during connecting report services thought SSMS

Tags: ssrs-2012, ssms-2012

HI i am getting problem to connect report service thought SSMS instance.

ERROR:

> Unable to connect to the server at . The specified URL
>   might not be valid or there might be a problem with the report server
>   version or configuration. Specify a different URL, or contact your
>   server administrator to verify that the report server runs SQL Server
>   2008 or later. Additionally, if you are trying to connect to a
>   SharePoint-integrated report server, verify that SharePoint is
>   installed on the server and that the report server uses SharePoint
>   integrated mode. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.RSClient)

i am using sql server 2012 i dont know why this error comes related to sql server 2008.

could any one help me.

Thanks,
Abhijeet D

Comment: Is the instance up and running?

Comment: Hi preet, sql server instance in runnig but when m going to connect Report Service instance it gives above error.